# Continuity of [1/x]

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Find the points of continuity and discontinuity 
of $\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$ (for $x \neq 0$)

Is the following argument alright?

We know that $[y]$ is continuous at every non-integer point
and discontinuous at every integer point. So, $\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]$ is also 
continuous at every $\frac{1}{x}$ which is non-integer point and 
discontinuous at every $\frac{1}{x}$ which is integer.
Therefore discontinuous at every $\frac{1}{x}$ equal to 
$\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3...$

that is, at every $x$ equal to $\pm 1, \ \pm \frac{1}{2}, \ \pm \frac{1}{3},...$

Comment: What does the notation [x] mean?

Comment: It denotes the greatest integer function

Comment: That's the correct answer.  But is that what they want?  Do they want a proof with definitions and argument or do they just want the answer?

Comment: " Is the following argument alright?"  That depends on what purpose the question was asked.  I would assume you are expected to prove the points of continuity of [x].  Also why should $[f (x)] only have discontinuity when f (x) is integer.  Does f (x) have its "own" discontinuity? And what if f (x) is an integer on an interval or is always an integer or slightly greater but not less.  All in all I wouldn't accept it.  But I can't say it is completely wrong either.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a fine (informal) argument to me. You can formalize this with $\epsilon-\delta$ without much issue.